# Remove squared background of the Android Studio "hello world"

Tags: android, android-studio

A Start a new project in Android Studio, but not found how remove or change squared background of the hello world application.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just an emulator artefact. Try it on a device?

Comment: You are correct. Tnks! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just an emulator artefact. If you try it on a device it will work.
(as solved in comments).

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay :D